# Rust: application getting deadlocked

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am new to rust and currently learning the concurrency chapter. In my current implementation I have created two traits namely `StartThread`(creates new thread inside `start` method which internally calls `run` method) and `TerminateThread`(for terminating thread; has two methods namely `stop` and `wait`). My implementation is currently getting deadlocked when stop method is called from main thread.

thread.rs

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

pub struct RunningThreadInterface<T> {
    pub instance: Arc<Mutex<T>>,
    pub thread_join_handle: thread::JoinHandle<()>,
}

pub trait StartThread<T> {
    fn start(self, thread_ID: String) -> RunningThreadInterface<T>;
    fn run(&mut self);
}

pub trait TerminateThread {
    fn stop(&mut self);
    fn wait(self);
}
```

NetworkReceiver.rs

```
use std::{thread, time};
use std::sync::{atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering}, Arc, Mutex};

use crate::thread::*;

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct NetworkReceiverThread {
    thread_ID: String,
    terminate_flag: AtomicBool,
}

impl NetworkReceiverThread {
    pub fn new() -> NetworkReceiverThread {
        NetworkReceiverThread {
            thread_ID: String::from(""),
            terminate_flag: AtomicBool::new(false),
        }
    }
}

impl StartThread<NetworkReceiverThread> for NetworkReceiverThread {
    fn start(mut self, thread_ID: String) -> RunningThreadInterface<NetworkReceiverThread> {
        self.thread_ID = thread_ID.clone();

        let network_receiver = Arc::new(Mutex::new(self));
        RunningThreadInterface {
            instance: Arc::clone(&network_receiver),
            thread_join_handle: thread::Builder::new().name(thread_ID).spawn(move || network_receiver.lock().unwrap().run()).ok().unwrap(),
        }
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        // let mut buff: [u8; 2048] = [0; 2048];

        while !self.terminate_flag.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            // receive network data and put into queue(will be processed by processor thread)
            println!("receiver thread");
            std::thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        }
    }
}

impl TerminateThread for RunningThreadInterface<NetworkReceiverThread> {
    fn stop(&mut self) {
        self.instance.lock().unwrap().terminate_flag.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }

    fn wait(self) {
        self.thread_join_handle.join();
    }
}
```

main.rs

```
mod thread;
mod NetworkReceiver;

use std::time;
use thread::*;
use NetworkReceiver::NetworkReceiverThread;

fn main() {
    let network_receiver = NetworkReceiverThread::new();

    let mut network_receiver: RunningThreadInterface<NetworkReceiverThread> = network_receiver.start(String::from("NT"));

    std::thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(5));

    network_receiver.stop();
    network_receiver.wait();
}
```

cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "ThreadChapter"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

Comment: Nit: Your code is full of unidomatic things. Listen to the warnings the compiler raises, and also run Clippy.

Answer (score 2):

The lock in `start()` is a temporary, and it is dropped at the end of the statement. So the whole time `run()` is running the lock is held, and when you're trying to acquire it it is still held.

The solution depends on your requirements. In this simple example, there is no need to use `Mutex` at all, since `AtomicBool` allows assignments via shared references:

thread.rs:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

pub struct RunningThreadInterface<T> {
    pub instance: Arc<T>,
    pub thread_join_handle: thread::JoinHandle<()>,
}

pub trait StartThread<T> {
    fn start(self, thread_ID: String) -> RunningThreadInterface<T>;
    fn run(&self);
}

pub trait TerminateThread {
    fn stop(&mut self);
    fn wait(self);
}
```

NetworkReceiver.rs:

```rust
use std::sync::{
    atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
    Arc,
};
use std::{thread, time};

use crate::thread::*;

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct NetworkReceiverThread {
    thread_ID: String,
    terminate_flag: AtomicBool,
}

impl NetworkReceiverThread {
    pub fn new() -> NetworkReceiverThread {
        NetworkReceiverThread {
            thread_ID: String::from(""),
            terminate_flag: AtomicBool::new(false),
        }
    }
}

impl StartThread<NetworkReceiverThread> for NetworkReceiverThread {
    fn start(mut self, thread_ID: String) -> RunningThreadInterface<NetworkReceiverThread> {
        self.thread_ID = thread_ID.clone();

        let network_receiver = Arc::new(self);
        RunningThreadInterface {
            instance: Arc::clone(&network_receiver),
            thread_join_handle: thread::Builder::new()
                .name(thread_ID)
                .spawn(move || network_receiver.run())
                .ok()
                .unwrap(),
        }
    }

    fn run(&self) {
        // let mut buff: [u8; 2048] = [0; 2048];

        while !self.terminate_flag.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            // receive network data and put into queue(will be processed by processor thread)
            println!("receiver thread");
            std::thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        }
    }
}

impl TerminateThread for RunningThreadInterface<NetworkReceiverThread> {
    fn stop(&mut self) {
        self.instance.terminate_flag.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }

    fn wait(self) {
        self.thread_join_handle.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to pass mutable reference to `run` method? The reason I need mutable reference is because I might need to mutate some member variables in the future implementations even though those member variable are not shared across threads. I am even open for a better thread design pattern.

Comment: @Harry Then wrap the other fields in a `Mutex`, not the `AtomicBool`.

Comment: wrapping each mutable member variable inside `Mutex` looks like a very bad software design. Can you suggest/guide a better way of designing the multiple thread creation and termination

Comment: @Harry You don't need to wrap every field in a different mutex, you can make an inner struct with all other fields and wrap it in mutex.